# Protocol Extension type Self does not match initializer types

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift2, swift-protocols

Let's say for academic purposes, I would prefer an expression like

```
someInt.asDouble
```

rather than the stock

```
Double(someInt)
```

Since all of the various Swift integer types conform to the `IntegerType` protocol AND because there seems to be a `Double()` initializer that fits every kind of those int types, I thought I could something like:

```
extension IntegerType {
    var asDouble:Double {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
```

This does not work. And I would like to know why? I would like to know if there is some magic that would make it work? A `where` maybe? Or something to do with the `self` reference?

The error I get in the console of the playground I tried in this reads:

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/2k/6y8rslzn1m95gjpg534j7v8jzr03tz/T/./lldb/41416/playground37.swift:31:10: error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Self)'
                return Double(self)
                       ^
/var/folders/2k/6y8rslzn1m95gjpg534j7v8jzr03tz/T/./lldb/41416/playground37.swift:31:10: note: overloads for 'Double' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Double), (UInt8), (Int8), (UInt16), (Int16), (UInt32), (Int32), (UInt64), (Int64), (UInt), (Int), (Float), (Float80), (String), (CGFloat), (NSNumber)
                return Double(self)
```

Comment: If you were a compiler, how would you find out which version is correct? it is impossible. there is a lot of similar questions around. our problem is to understand that swift it type safe language ....

Comment: `Int` is the thing that holds the value. Not one of the protocols it conforms to.

Comment: @RMenke Does that mean that a Protocol Extension cannot refer to `self`?

Answer (score 3):

All `IntegerType` types can be promoted to `IntMax`, and `IntMax` can be converted to `Double`.

```
extension IntegerType {
    var asDouble: Double {
        return Double(self.toIntMax())
    }
}
```

As you suggest, this is not a particularly useful thing to do (`Double(x)` is the correct syntax), but it may be useful for other problems.

I would continue stdlib's pattern if I were going to create this. The pattern is `toX()` rather than `asX`:

```
extension IntegerType {
    func toDouble() -> Double {
        return Double(self.toIntMax())
    }
}
```

See also `toOpaque()` and `toUIntMax()`. `as` suggests a simple reinterpretation of the type without copying, and a `var` suggests that it's a property of this value. That's not what's happening. You're actually converting it to a different value, stored in a different format, that may not even be equal. (For large integers, there may be rounding errors such that `x != Int(x.toDouble())`.)

It's worth also reading [Trying to extend IntegerType (and FloatingPointType); Why can't all Int types be converted to NSTimeInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620967/trying-to-extend-integertype-and-floatingpointtype-why-cant-all-int-types-be/33657549#33657549), which discusses the problem further, along with why similar features can be dangerous unless done with great care.

Comment: @Rob Napier excelent !! really very useful answer !!

Comment: @Rob Napier how to deal with FloatingPointType ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620967/trying-to-extend-integertype-and-floatingpointtype-why-cant-all-int-types-be/33657549#33657549. This whole approach is pretty useless, since `Double(x)` is by far the better solution in this case, and I give the better solution for `NSTimeInterval` at the bottom of the linked answer. But in theory, it could be useful for some other thing that exceeds its danger. (I explain the dangers in the linked answer as well.)

Comment: @Rob Napier i need 'generic' version of math functions. in standard library there are, for example, round(Double), round(Float) .... it is fine for me first convert everything to Double, but i have no idea how. does exist something similar to .toIntMax() for FloatingPointType ???

Comment: See the previously linked question (final paragraph above). I provide a `TimeIntervalConvertible` protocol there. `DoubleConvertible` would be identical. I also explain why converting to `Double` isn't the same as converting to `IntMax`, so some care must be taken.